# Setting shipping info in OmniPay

Tags: paypal, omnipay

I'm trying to set a shipping info (name,address, email, etc) using OmniPay for **PayPal Express**.
I've tried adding shipping info in options array in `purchase($options)` object:

```
$options = array(
// required fields (username, pass, etc) 
// .....
'shippingAddress1' => 'Elm Street'
'shippingCity' => 'Elm', 
'shippingPostcode' => '1000'
// etc. 
);
```

I also tried passing this info to `CreditCard` object:

`$card = new Omnipay\Common\CreditCard($card_options);`
without any success. The code:

```
$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('PayPal_Express');
        $gateway->setUsername(USERNAME);
        $gateway->setPassword(PASS);
        $gateway->setSignature(SIGNATURE);
        $gateway->setTestMode(true);

        $card_options = array(
         'shippingAddress1' => 'Elm Street',
         'shippingCity' => 'Elm',
         'shippingPostcode' => '10000',
         'shippingState' => '',
         'shippingCountry' => 'NEverland',
         'shippingPhone' => '123465789',
         'company' => '',
         'email' => 'shipping@test.com'
         );
        $card = new Omnipay\Common\CreditCard($card_options);

        $response = $gateway->purchase(
            array(
                'cancelUrl'=>'http://localhost/laravel_paypal/',
                'returnUrl'=>'http://localhost/laravel_paypal/public/paypalexpress_confirm',
                'amount' =>  '0.99',
                'currency' => 'USD',
                'card' => $card

            )
        )->send();
```

How to add shipping info to **PayPal Express** using OmniPay?

BTW, I'm using **Laravel** with **PayPal Sandbox**.

Comment: Found a workaround.
Class `ExpressAuthorizeRequest` in `getData()` method has haardcoded value for setting shipping prompt upon payment on PayPal.
 `$data['NOSHIPPING'] = 1;`

Comment: If you change the value to `2`, then when redirected to PayPal Express page there will be option for setting shipping info (if necessary). I wish that this could be done with getters/setters on `purchase()` object

Comment: Good point. I've made an issue for you here, will address this in a future version. For now probably easiest just to fork and edit the file directly. https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay/issues/121

Comment: If you don't need shipping (paying for a service) use 'noShipping' => true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has recently been fixed (https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay/pull/140) so it should now be possible to set shipping info properly.