# Hi iam sending card details via paypal omnipay. payment showing success but not appearing in paypal

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.8, omnipay

1. Hi I am ingerating paypal/omnipay. o am sending credit card details
           to paypal,this is showing success. but i cannot find any of the
           transactions in my paypal sandbox account.
                 My code is like this:

   ```
                  $card = new CreditCard($formData);
                  $response = $this->gateway->purchase(
               [
                   'amount' => '10.00',
                   'currency' => 'USD',
                   'card' => $card ,
                   'returnUrl' =>url('/paypalreturn'),
                   'cancelUrl' =>url('/cancelpaypal'),
               ]## Heading ##
           )->send(); 
   the response from paypal like

     "TOKEN" => "EC-262806394V614015G"
       "TIMESTAMP" => "2019-07-25T16:40:24Z"
       "CORRELATIONID" => "3cc9ebc7e1458"
       "ACK" => "Success"
       "VERSION" => "119.0"
       "BUILD" => "53374502"
   ```

all is going well , except i cannot see the transaction in paypal sandbox.Can any one tell me where i am going
            wrong? Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Are you using the sandbox server?  Those transactions will not show up in your real paypal account only in your sandbox account.

Comment: I am using sandbox server. But not showing in my sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

after a long research i found out that paypal rest api is the best answer for this question. after a long headache i found the answer here : [Does the creditCard function exist in Omnipay PayPal Express? Or only in PayPal Pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277335/does-the-creditcard-function-exist-in-omnipay-paypal-express-or-only-in-paypal)
Hope this helps some one